# c# How to convert from GetType() to T

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a method that receives a generic T

```
Data.Helpers.EntityKeyHelper.Instance.GetKeyNames<T>(this);
```

Where T should be:

```
Type entityType = dbEntry.Entity.GetType();
```

So I need to pass:

```
Data.Helpers.EntityKeyHelper.Instance.GetKeyNames<entityType>(this);
```

But it's sending me an error:

```
The type or namespace name 'entityType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any clue on how can I covert dbEntry.Entity to T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), first you need to get `GetKeyNames` method  then:

```
method.MakeGenericMethod(dbEntry.Entity.GetType())
 .Invoke(yourInstance, new object[] { this });
```

Comment: How can I get my string[]? What does "yourInstance" is?

Comment: Invoke returns the result as object. you could cast it to string[]

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

- Make your method generic on `T`, passing the problem up to your caller (who may know the type at compile-time)
- Change the method to accept a `Type` parameter instead of being generic (not usually feasible, but from the name `GetKeyNames<T>` it might well be here)
- Use reflection to provide the generic argument at runtime, and create a delegate that you can call.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the MakeGenericMethod and other offered choices, there's an extra one: making that C# infers it for you based on the parameters:

```
List<T> GetKeyNames<T>(object whatever, T entity){
   ....
}

// Then you call it like this
Data.Helpers.EntityKeyHelper.Instance.GetKeyNames(this, dbEntry.Entity);
```

This way, C# will know what T is because it will take it from the "dbEntry.Entity"